# How to find Conan remote package settings

Tags: linux, package-managers, conan

Every Conan package has some settings e.g. **compiler, compiler version, architecture** etc. On Conan center, multiple binary versions are uploaded based on settings of package. How can I find the set of settings value of a remote package?

```
conan inspect <package-name>  --raw=settings
```

does not give the value of settings. I want to know settings before fetching package so that I can select exact revision of the package. Or I can search availability of a package with specific set of settings value.

Comment: ``conan inspect`` inspect only the recipe. But the settings values do not belong to the recipe, but to every specific package. You can use the ``conan get`` command, providing the full reference, including the ``package_id`` of the binary you want to use. In any case, what you are trying to do is an anti-pattern. You don't look for a revision with the settings and then use it, you feed the settings (profile, command line), and that will be resolved to a binary. If it doesn't exist, it needs to be built.

Comment: You can probably navigate the existing packages with ``conan search zlib/1.2.11@ -r=conancenter``, and with the ``--table=zlib.html`` it can give you an interactive table to inspect those binaries. But even in that case, it is not good practice to try to use a specific ``package_id``, it cannot be even specified in ``conan install``, the ``package_id`` is always computed, not an input.